# How to output a resized Assets image in a template

Tags: assets, image-transforms, image

How can I output a resized Assets image in a single entry template? I'm trying to do what I used to do all the time with CE Image in EE. I'm hoping that I don't have to create an image transform in the CP for every single piece of image resizing that I want to do as that would be very time consuming (compared to using the CE Image parameters for width and height in EE).

Here's my current code:

```
{% for asset in entry.mainImage %}
  <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

And for EE users, here's what I'm trying to replicate from EE:

```
{cf_static_image}
  {exp:ce_img:single src="{url}" width="800" height="600" alt="{alt_text}"}
{/cf_static_image}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Update: Here's what my final code looked like after following the example in the link provided by Brad below:

```
{% set thumb = {
  mode: 'fit',
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  quality: 80
} %}

{% for asset in entry.mainImage %}
  <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(thumb) }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create and specify transform parameters from your templates to achieve what you're looking for.  See [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/image-transforms#defining-transforms-in-your-templates) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for this Brad. I've updated my question with what my final code ended up like after checking out that example.